# Как привязать коллекцию уже к существующей коллекции Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-database, swiftui

Мне нужно создать коллекцию "retweets" и поместить ее именно в какую-то определенную коллекцию ("tweets") чтобы "retweets" сохранялись именно для одной записи, которую я выбрал. Коллекция создается но создается в один ряд с коллекциями "tweets" мне же надо, чтобы "retweets" сохранялось внутри одной из коллекций "tweets"

**Константы**

```
let COLLECTION_TWEETS = Firestore.firestore().collection("wishes")
let COLLECTION_RETWEETS = COLLECTION_TWEETS.document().collection("retweets")
```

**Функция загрузки**

```
    func uploadRetweet(retweet: UIImage) {
        guard let user = AuthViewModel.shared.user else { return }
        
        let docRef = COLLECTION_RETWEETS.document()
        
        let data: [String: Any] = ["uid": user.id,
                                   "retweetimage": retweet.pngData()!,
                                   "fullname":user.fullname,
                                   "timestamp": Timestamp(date: Date()),
                                   "username": user.username,
                                   "profileImageUrl": user.profileImageUrl,
                                   "likes": 0,
                                   "id": docRef.documentID]

        
        docRef.setData(data) { _ in
            self.isPresented = false
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать в "tweet" свойство "retweets" и там хранить массив retweets:

```
var retweets = [Any]()

retweets.append...

let tweet: [String: Any] = [
...
"retweets": retweets
...
]
```

Тогда в каждой записи tweet, будет своя коллекция retweets.